# ndb Singleton Pattern

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm doing an online store in appengine, and I'm creating a model that will hold the settings of the store in the db, the code looks something like this:

```
class StoreSettings(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    homepageTitle = ndb.StringProperty()
    metaKeywords = ndb.StringProperty()
    metaDescription = ndb.StringProperty()
    timezone = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    currency = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Is there an easy way to make the StoreSettings class to be a singleton?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize your settings you can provide a key_name, then when you have to retrieve it you can use `get_or_insert` method. If it doesn't exist it will create it otherwise it will retrieve it.

```
settings_db = StoreSettings.get_or_insert(
    'my_settings',
    name='yourname'
    ....
)
```

Or if you create the object when your application starts then you can just get it by the key name

`settigns_db = StoreSettings.get_by_id('my_settings')`

Answer (score 0):

Keep the same key? whenever you push an entity in the datastore, it needs a key.

If you create a second object with the same key, it ends up over-writing the previous entity.